# Coalesce whole records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I'm currently coallescing fields individually in MySQL queries, but I would like to coalesce whole records.

Is this possible?

```
SELECT la.id, 
COALESCE(( SELECT name FROM lookup_changed l0, 
           ( SELECT MAX(id) id 
             FROM lookup_changed     
             WHERE lookup_id = 26
           ) l1 
           WHERE l0.id = l1.id
         ), la.name) name,
COALESCE(( SELECT msisdn FROM lookup_changed l0, 
           ( SELECT MAX(id) id 
             FROM lookup_changed     
             WHERE lookup_id = 26
           ) l1 
           WHERE l0.id = l1.id
         ), la.msisdn) msisdn
FROM lookup_added la
WHERE la.id = 26
```

@Alma Do - the pseudo-SQL is:

```
SELECT la.id, 
MULTICOALESCE(( SELECT <name, msisdn> FROM lookup_changed l0, 
                ( SELECT MAX(id) id 
                  FROM lookup_changed     
                  WHERE lookup_id = 26
                ) l1 
                WHERE l0.id = l1.id
              ), <la.name, la.msisdn>) <name, msisdn>
FROM lookup_added la
WHERE la.id = 26
```

Comment: I didn't get the sense. Can you provide pseudo-SQL  ?(i.e. how it should look like)

Answer (score 0):

Since `COALESCE()` "return[s] the first non-NULL argument", it sounds like you want to retreive the "first non-NULL result from a set for queries":

```
-- syntax error
SELECT COALESCE(
    SELECT a FROM ta,
    SELECT b FROM tb
);

-- roughly equates to
( SELECT a AS val FROM ta WHERE a IS NOT NULL ORDER BY a LIMIT 1 )
UNION
( SELECT b AS val FROM tb WHERE b IS NOT NULL ORDER BY b LIMIT 1 )
ORDER BY val LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comments:

- I added `ORDER BY` clauses, otherwise "first row" means nothing
- the inner `LIMIT 1` clauses are optional (but allow early trimming of sub-results)
- the parenthesis around the sub queries are mandatory